# How can this code be modified to increase the number of months instead of days?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Please help. I have a form with textbox 3 for the start date of the installments and another textbox 6 for the payment period for one installment per month, and the number of 15 textboxes from H1 to H15.
It is required to modify this code so that the number of months increases from the date of the installment, as it increases the number of days.

```
For i = 1 To 15
     If i = 1 Then
         Me("h" & i) = TextBox3.Text
     Else
         Me("h" & i) = Format(CDate(Me.TextBox3.Value) + i - 1, "dd/mm/yyyy")
     End If
Next i
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ58H.jpg)

It is required to modify this code so that the number of months increases from the date of the installment, as it increases the number of days.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8xKl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use [dateadd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function).

```vb
For i = 1 To 15
    If i = 1 Then
        Me("h" & i) = TextBox3.Text
    Else
        Me("h" & i) = Format(DateAdd("m", i-1, CDate(Me.TextBox3.Value)), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: It works well and increases the months by one month for each date. Is it possible to modify it to increase the number of months according to what is written in Textbox 6? Thank you for your interest and speed.

Comment: `For i = 1 to 15 step Textbox6.value` or something along those lines?

Comment: Unfortunately not working

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet (lack reputation), otherwise i would, you said that the "step" suggestion by Forward Ed is not working, is the value in textbox6 a number?? if for instance its "6 months" that won't work, if its a number you could check if its formatted as a number, in the second image it says 3, but i may be a string "3", you should check that, if it's a string, use CInt(textbox6.value)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with vba, so I'm trying to apply your comments to the code, and yes, what's in a textbox is the number of months to be increased, and I applied your notes as a series, and I achieved the required, but leaving two empty textboxes between each date For example, textbox 1 date, then textbox 2, textbox 3 is empty, then textbox 4 has a date, and so on
And thanks for your patience

Comment: For i = 1 To 15 Step CInt(TextBox6.Value)
If i = 1 Then
        Me("h" & i) = TextBox3.Text
    Else
        Me("h" & i) = Format(DateAdd("m", i, CDate(Me.TextBox3.Value)), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    End If
Next i

Comment: it seems like you are not looping as you should, but i may need to see more code to help you (i'm not an expert just a noob trying to help :P)

Comment: You need to add whatever is in textbox6 per textbox, and what you seem to be doing is loop thru the textboxes and jumping by whatever is in textbox 6...

Also you COULD potencially make use of the naming capability, name your textboxes with something descriptive enough, and you can use that to loop thru them, for example the first one could be "tb_Numbofmonths", the "tb_" referes to textbox, the ones with dates tb_date1 tb_date2 tb_date3, etc

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/TaxOqI8.png in case you need it...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).